# Set min value for numeric textbox in Kendo ui template

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to prevent negative values in Kendo numeric textbox template as below:

```
<input type="text"  data-type="number" data-format="n0" name="SnoozeLength" data-bind="value:snoozeLength" data-role="numerictextbox" />
```

is there any attributes which i can use line "min-value= 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/numerictextbox#configuration-min

You can specify min configuration for your numerictextbox.

Best Regards,